# Yocto Bitbake doesn't include kernel config fragment in build

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, intel, yocto, bitbake

I am currently trying to setup docker on my yocto (thud - 2.6) project. For that, I need to enable some kernel configuration.

The problem is that the kernel config fragment is not included in the build.

To include the config fragment I created a custom layer with the following structure

```
meta-edge_controller
|__conf
|   |__layer.conf
|__recipes-kernel
    |__linux
        |__linux-intel
        |   |__docker_required.cfg
        |__linux-intel_4.14.bbappend
```

linux-intel_4.14.bbappend

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URL += "file://docker_required.cfg"
```

docker_required.cfg

```
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST=y
CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPRANGE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_LIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RECENT=y
CONFIG_IP_VS=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV4=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MANGLE=y
CONFIG_BTRFS_FS=y
CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS=y
```

I am builing for an Intel based Board (Atom E3940) and I have integrated the meta-intel layer, using the machine type "intel-corei7-64".

How can I further debug or investigate why bitbake doesn't include the kernel config fragment?

I also tried rebuilding the kernel manually: `bitbake -c cleanall linux-intel` and `bitbake linux-intel`

Comment: At first glance, it seems correct. Have you double checked the settings of your layer and bblayers conf files? Maybe `meta-edge_controller` is not being taken into account. You can use `bitbake-layers show-layers` to perform a quick-check.

Comment: To complete @danlor comment, do you use linux-intel 4.14 or 4.19?

Answer (score 2):

I see a typo in your snippet. `SRC_URL` should be `SRC_URI` instead. More info [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SRC_URI).